# ArcCosh[x] and ArcTanh[x/Sqrt[x^2-1] have the same derivative but I cannot prove their equality

Tags: calculus

Derivative of ArcCosh[x/a] for x>a>0 is 1/Sqrt[x^2-a^2].
Derivative of ArcTanh[x/Sqrt[x^2-a^2]] is also 1/Sqrt[x^2-a^2].
However, I am not able to prove that ArcCosh[x/a]=ArcTanh[x/Sqrt[x^2-a^2]]+constant
Any help??

Comment: You _have_ proven that they are equal up to a constant (assuming it's correct, I haven't checked). Maybe you meant to say that you want to prove it through trigonometry rather than calculus?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2183650/42969

Comment: Arthur, this is what Mathematica gives. I would like to prove it using trigonometry.